# Not git flow enabled repo error on soucetree

Tags: github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

Trying to create a hotfix but keep getting this error:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably this can help you? https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/259554/how-do-i-resolve-the-not-a-gitflow-enabled-repo-error-when-attempting-to-start-a-feature

Comment: Did you run `git flow init` in the relevant folder?

Answer (score 0):

Did not have a develop branch created. Created one and it solved my problem